# .NET RegEx replace escape character with tag

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some text from an old database. The text is formatted like this:

> This is the first part of the text #this should be formatted in bold#
>   this should be normal text and then #this should be formatted in bold
>   again# and so on.

As you can see above, I need to find all the groups that are inside # signs, and set a `<b></b>` or `<strong></strong>` tag around them. How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = @"This is the first part of the text #this should be formatted in bold# this should be normal text and then #this should be formatted in bold again# and so on.";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"#(.+?)#", "<b>$1</b>");
```